# Is there a widely accepted reason for the formation of tafoni?

Tags: geology, rocks, geomorphology, erosion, weathering

Expansion of tafoni seems to be based on weathering (seems reasonable enough.) But **what creates them in the first place**? There are a number of explanations online (Wikipedia lists eight plausible causes!) Many websites trying to give a simplified explanation simply say "salt weathering", but from a brief search it's clear that salt weathering is not always the cause of tafoni [0]. They develop on a wide range of rock types, from granite to sandstone to tuffs and conglomerates, and in many situations where they'd be expected to develop they don't.

From what I can tell, they seem somewhat mysterious, and there are explanations that make sense in some cases but not every case of tafoni is well explained. Is there a widely accepted explanation for the formation of tafoni?

Picture of tafoni (Martin Sharman, Wikipedia):

[image]

[0] for example: page 75, Arid and Semi-Arid Geomorphology, Andrew S. Goudie

Comment: [Here are some pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pirunpes%C3%A4%20Jalasj%C3%A4rvell%C3%A4%20kuvat&tbm=isch) of a supposed tafoni in Finland (a natural 23 m deep hole in bedrock in the municipality of Jalasjärvi). Preferential weathering is the preferred geological explanation. If you wish to see the place, come within seven years from now since the rental of the place elapses after that date.

Comment: @HeikkiSärkkä Looks like an interesting place! However, that does not look anything like tafoni to me. Perhaps you're confusing it with another place that does have tafoni, also called the Devil's Nest and located in Finland: https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/pirunpesa-the-devils-nest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a good geomorphology teacher. He was so good that I bought his book, published on Prentince Hall at 2008. He is an aged an experimented geomorphologist, so I totaly trust there is not an agreement about the physical origin of tafonies (or at least there wasn't an agreement at 2008 when his book was published).

> "Its origin [tafonis] is controversial (Twidale and Vidal Romaní, 2005). Some authors differentiate between wall tafonis and basal tafonis, linked to the processes of basal undermining (Smith, 1978, Bradley et al., 1978). It is agreed that the dominant processes are those related to the movement of water with salts close to the surface, which correspond to haloclastism and wetting and drying. Thermoclastism, cryoclasty, dissolution of carbonated cements and wind erosion are also mentioned (Evans, 1969-70, Mustoe, 1983, Young, 1987, Robinson and Williams, 1992). In addition to these subaerial processes, some taphonis can be generated by weathering under the soil surface and subsequent exhumation by erosion (Dragovich, 1969)."
>
> **Source**: [Geomorfología, Prentince Hall (2008)](https://www.casadellibro.com/libro-geomorfologia/9788483223895/1197545), page 152. 
>   Translated from spanish by Google.

-Gutiérrez Elorza, M. (2008) "Geomorfología". Ed Prentince Hall.

-Twidale, C. R.; Bourne, J.A., y Vidal Romaní, J.R. (2005): "Beach etching and shore platforms" *Geomorphology* 67, 47-61.

-Smith (1978) "The origin and geomorphic implications of cliff foot recesses and tafoni on limestone hamadas in the northwest Sahara" *Zeitscrift für Geomorphologie*, 22, 21-43.

-Bradley, W.C.; hutton, J.T., y Twidale, C.R.(1978). "Role of salts in development of granitic tafoni, South Australia". *Journal of Geology* 86, 647-654.

-Evans, I.S. (1969-70) "Salt crystallization and rock weathering: a review" *Revue de Géomorphologié Dynamique*, 19,153-177.

-Mustoe, G.E.(1983)"Cavernous weathering in the Capitol Reef Desert, Utah" *Earth Surface Processes and Landforms* 8, 517-526

-Young, R.M. (1987) "Salt as an agent in the development of cavernous weathering" *Geology* 15, 962-966.

-Robinson, D.A. Williams, R.B.G.(1992) "Sandstone weathering in the High Atlas, morocco" *Zeitscrift für Geomorphologie* 4,413-429.

-Dragovich, D. (1969): "The origin of cavernous surfaces (tafoni) in granitic rocks of Southern Australia". *Zeitscrift für Geomorphologie* 13, 163-181.

Comment: It is importan to note processes may differ within the different types of rocks where tafonies are developed.

Comment: Ah, beautiful! This is exactly what I was looking for - multiple credible recent sources saying there was not (or was) a consensus! I'm pretty convinced. It'd be nice to have some sort of literature review here, I'm quite surprised none exists. Still, without one, I suppose this is the next best thing. Thank you!

Comment: @Owen Versteeg. You are welcome and thanks for accepting my answer. Glad to help. They are not very recent quotes but trustable sources. I think multiple proccess are involved at different climates and rocks where this forms develops so the proccesses involved in its formation vary from regions/rocks. The book mention tafonis take a lot of time (some million years) to form.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if anyone is still interested in this question, but I am doing research on Uluru (a.k.a Ayers Rock), Australia, and the Mitten Ridge Sinkhole in Sedona, AZ (A very interesting combination of locations.).

I have a photo just outside the sinkhole showing the sidewall of the Supai Sandstone. The sandstone is pitted just like honey-comb tafoni. Uluru has the caves everyone is familiar with around much of its base and some armchairs and other gnamma structures from its base to its peak, and a few tafoni that Twidale identifies on its sides. Uluru also has a coat of hematite completely covering it, 2-3 cm thick. Everyone wants to produce hematite from rust or a biogenic source, but the only way I can prove the formation of that much hematite, that thick, is by a great deal of heat, 800-1000 °C. It is done with terracotta clay in ceramics class regularly.

The Mitten Ridge sinkhole was formed by hot gas from the mantle, hot enough to melt garnet, 1950 °C. The ceiling of the sinkhole is covered with tiny garnet crystals that could only have formed in cooling gas. The sinkhole is as far as the gas could melt its way through the strata moving up, maybe 1.5 km height, and it melted its way out into the air, and the tafoni in the sandstone is part of that pathway.

So tafoni are holes melted in the rock when a great heating event happened. I would be glad to post several photos if anyone is interested and can tell me how. Otherwise the papers will go to journals in the next couple of weeks and you can see them there eventually. I will also be glad to correspond with anyone interested on this topic since this only scratches the very surface.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting contribution. If you would like to include photographs in your answer I find it easier to first load them onto the computer I'm using when posting answer on Stack Exchange. Under your answer selection **Edit** option in gray at the bottom left. Place the computer cursor marker where you want to include a photo. At the header to the Edit section there will be some icons, select the one that looks like a 2D picture of a mountain. When the panel pops up select *Browse* to navigate to where you loaded your photos. Select a photo & follow the instruction in the panel.

Comment: Your comment about hematite on Uluru is interesting. It's the first I've come across. All other sources I've come across, until now, explain the red color as [oxidation of iron within the gray arkose sandstone that composes Uluru](https://parksaustralia.gov.au/uluru/discover/nature/geology/).

Answer (score 0):

It is called preferential weathering, but there is another element at play. Before the rock eroded into circular features, there were softer materials present. Those softer materials weathered away first leaving the more resistant host rock (or matrix) behind. The matrix is harder than the softer "clastic" material. When pebbles get washed into the cliff face, the pebbles will slowly break down the softer material first and eventually the wave-action of pebbles will continue to grind as they spin and get rolled around in these little crevasses, which can grow in size as is seen in many Tafoni rock faces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I'm not convinced. I've seen this explanation all over the internet and it hand waves over the whole interesting part here, aka the weird pattern. Why, exactly, does the weathering happen in this specific way? And if the explanation is so straightforward, then why is the formation of tafoni so unpredictable? I'm leaning towards the other answer to this question, which cites a number of sources (some quite recent) saying there are many competing hypotheses but no agreement in the field as to their origin.